# Floor affects ball force direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a pool game. The ball has a trajectory direction and I move the ball using AddForce. My problem right now is if the ball is touching the floor it's direction will go a little offcourse while if it doesn't touch the floor the direction is pretty accurate. What can be the cause of this? Btw, I have set the angular drag and drag to 0 same as friction

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the floor is using a box collider and not a mesh collider, in case maybe the mesh has some deformities. Check the same for the billiard balls that they are using sphere colliders. It also sounds like maybe the floor could be at a slight angle, so be sure to check the rotation of its GameObject as well as all its parents in the hierarchy.